# getting tr index in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below table and I am using the below code to get the index of the tr with the id tbl1.The issue is that the index being returned which should be 2 is coming out correct in IE but it is coming as 3 in chrome and firefox.Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

```
var parent = document.getElementById("tbl1").parentElement;
    var tr = document.getElementById("tbl1");
    var index = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < parent.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (parent.childNodes.item(i) == tr) {
            index = ++i;
            break;
        }
    }

<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0><TBODY>
<TR>
</TR>
<TR id="tbl1">
</TR>
<TR></TR>
</TBODY></TABLE>
```

Comment: that because of newlines. IE, for example, interprets newlines as childNodes

Comment: If you use a library like jQuery a lot of cross browser problems go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just use `rowIndex`:

```
var tr = document.getElementById("tbl1"),
    index = tr.rowIndex + 1;

console.log(index);  // => 2
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LHqmK/)

Answer (score 1):

I know you didn't ask for a solution using jQuery, anyway:

```
$('#tbl1').index()+1
```

gives you 2 as well.

It works for any kind of node, not only TR.