# JS: how to get tbody index in table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with many tbodies inside. For example:

```
<table id="tableId">
 <tbody id="tbodyId">
   <tr><td>1</td></tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr><td>2</td></tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
   <tr><td>3</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I need these tbody for grouping rows with span. How can I get certain tbody index in table via js? I mean:

```
var tbody=....;
var table=....;
var tbodyIndex=?
```

For example, for rows we can use `rowIndex`, but for tbodies?

**EDIT**
Special edit for some users:

```
var tbody=document.getElementById("tbodyId");
var table=document.getElementById("tableId");
var tbodyIndex=?
```

Comment: Your code sample doesn't really clarify anything, and I don't know what you mean by "grouping rows with span". Could you give us some more detail?

Comment: Isn't it duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887162/getting-tr-index-in-a-table?rq=1 ?

Comment: Just iterate through [`HTMLTableElement.tBodies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.tBodies) collection and when you've found the wanted element, you'll have an index too.

Comment: And which TBODY you want the index???

Comment: @Teemu If you could provide example how I could get certain tbody index from this collection I would be very thankful to you.

Comment: Yeah, sure, immediately after you'll answer A. Wolff's question ; ).

Comment: @A. Wolff Are you serious? Do you want to say that my question depends of what tbody I want get index?

Comment: @iJava It depends how you want to target any specific TBODY, following user interaction or what? Your posted code is `var tbody=....;`, really doesn't help that much

Comment: @A. Wolff I edited special for you.

Comment: @iJava Looks like A. Wolff would have a good answer for you, no need to [iterate](http://jsfiddle.net/L6n1g0wv/) ; ). Though you definitely can't group rows with a span.

Comment: @Teemu But as `Array.prototype.indeOf` method isn't supported by older browser as IE8 (even many polyfills exist), your jsFiddle is still a good workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
var tbody=document.getElementById("tbodyId");
var table=document.getElementById("tableId");
var tbodyIndex= [].slice.call(table.tBodies).indexOf(tbody); // [].slice.call() to convert HTML collection to array
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: Thank you. Interesting solution. Just it's pitty it took me so long to explain.

Comment: @iJava because `get certain tbody index` is really vague ;)

Comment: @iJava Indeed ya, rereading your question, don't know what i was thinking about...